# Ajax not working on live Server

Tags: php, ajax

I want to fetch data from a PHP File

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showUsers(str) {
   if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("zzips").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("zzips").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getstate.php"+str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

```
<select name="state_hid" required onchange="showUsers(this.value);">
    <option>AL</option><option>AK</option>      
    <option>AZ</option><option>AR</option>
    <option>CA</option>
    <option>CO</option>
    <option>CT</option><option>DE</option><option>FL</option>          
    <option>GA</option>
</select>
<select id="zzips" name="zzip"> 

</select>
```

PHP file
          
           $sql=mysql_query("Select* From zipcod Where abb='".$isd."' ") or die('error');

```
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
           $zip=$row['zip'];
           echo '<option>'.$zip.'</option> '; 
         }   
      mysql_close( $sql );

        ?>
```

This Ajax is Working fine on Localhost but when i upload the same code on live server it is not working . Does anyone have any idea.

Please advice.

Comment: check for errors in console...

Comment: check in console what you get return on ajax request in console

Comment: do it like this `<option value="ca">CA</option>` for all options add `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)I think this

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "getstate.php"+str, true);
```

should be

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "fullpath/getstate.php?q="+str, true);
```

2)And there is no value in the option field

3)Try accessing directly in your browser

```
path_to_file/getstate.php?q='CA'
```

4) Check the file permission of getstate.php file

Comment: ok i ghave give the full path now . I have one more file in Getstate.php  as stateconfig.php.  SHould i give the full path to stateconfig.php As this is a wordpress website

Comment: no! its not working. how ever when i gave the full path Script it dosnt show any console error

Comment: type your full path in the web browser directly and see if it works

Comment: Ok Man Great I found the Problem and its working Now. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide full absolute path from http://domain.com/filepath in your

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getstate.php"+str, true);
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://path-to/getstate.php"+str, true);
```

replace path-to with your full path

Hope this helps..